# Error: The path '\cd\3a92d.... \' does not exist on this computer

Tags: ftp, remote-access

I'm trying to connect remotely to the server via ftp-simple, VS Code shows me this error:

> "Error: The path '\cd\3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4 ' does not exist on this computer. " - nothing happens after that - there is no connection...

In output console I have:

```
[2022-05-31 15:41:34] test - FTP Connecting...
[2022-05-31 15:41:35] test - FTP open!!
[2022-05-31 15:41:35] cd /
[2022-05-31 15:41:36] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.appdata/[DIR] backups
[2022-05-31 15:41:36] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.appdata/[DIR] current
[2022-05-31 15:41:36] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/application_backups/app_dom-in-pro_Test_2022-05-26_02-35-55.tar.gz
[2022-05-31 15:41:36] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.bash_logout
[2022-05-31 15:41:36] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.bash_profile
[2022-05-31 15:41:36] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.bashrc
[2022-05-31 15:41:36] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.cagefs/[DIR] opt
[2022-05-31 15:41:36] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.cagefs/[DIR] tmp
[2022-05-31 15:41:36] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.cagefs/[DIR] var
[2022-05-31 15:41:36] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.clipboard.txt
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.cl.selector/defaults.cfg
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/domains/[DIR] dom-in.pro
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/domains/[DIR] qiciqciomj.cfolks.pl
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/imap/[DIR] dom-in.pro
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/imap/[DIR] qiciqciomj.cfolks.pl
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.lvestats/lvestats_notifications_off
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.php/php-mail.log
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.php/php-mail.log.1
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.php/php-mail.log.10
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.php/php-mail.log.11
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.php/php-mail.log.2
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.php/php-mail.log.3
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.php/php-mail.log.4
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.php/php-mail.log.5
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.php/php-mail.log.6
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.php/php-mail.log.7
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.php/php-mail.log.8
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.php/php-mail.log.9
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/public_html
[2022-05-31 15:41:37] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.shadow
[2022-05-31 15:41:38] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.spamassassin/user_prefs
[2022-05-31 15:41:38] Remote info download : cd/3a92d3d9babd44c3207fb1455e0891d4/.zshrc
```

Comment: You need to post source code if you want someone to be able to help you.

Comment: `[
 {
  "name": "Test",
  "host": "s172.cyber-folks.pl",
  "port": 21,
  "type": "ftp",
  "username": "*********",
  "password": "**********",
  "path": "/",
  "autosave": true,
  "confirm": true
 }
]`